# winner in German: Überwinder m, Besieger m, Bezwinger m, Sieger m, Gewinner , Erster m

Tags: vocabulary

I have translated *winner* into German. I have more translations: *Überwinder* m, *Besieger* m, *Bezwinger* m, *Sieger* m, *Gewinner* , *Erster* m.

I am studying the difference between them.

- *Überwinder* m = (no entry) - DWDS
- *Besieger* m = (no entry) - DWDS
- *Sieger* m = "jmd., der gesiegt hat" - DWDS
- *Gewinner* m = "jmd., der in einem Kampf, Wettkampf, im Spiel gewonnen hat" - DWDS
- *Erster* m = (no entry) - DWDS

Frequency of them used in [books by ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%9Cberwinder%2CBesieger%2CBezwinger%2CSieger%2CGewinner%2CErster&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%9Cberwinder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBesieger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBezwinger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSieger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGewinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CErster%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Hypothesis: Gewinner m is a winner of a bet, or lottery maybe.

Am I right? What is the difference?

Comment: There are 4+3+2+1 = 10 Differences between 5 Words. That's too broad a question. If you dictionary lacks entries for half of your questions, choose a different one. I suggest closing due to broadness and gen. reference. Why should frequency be important?

Comment: You can look up the differences among the verbs originating those nouns. That will clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

> Sieger

The word "*siegen*" means: "To win" in the context of a sports event, a game, a battle in war ... however **not** in the lottery or in gambling.

Therefore the "*Sieger*" can be the winner of a sports event, of a game or in a war the army who has won a battle, ...

After a war "*Sieger*" can also be the country which won the war.

This explains the two peaks in the diagram at 1920 and 1945: It is the time after the war.

> Gewinner

Your hypothesis is correct: The winner of a lottery is called "*Gewinner*" and not "*Sieger*".

The winner of a bet is also typically called "*Gewinner*" and only rarely "*Sieger*" - even if there is no prize to win.

The word "*gewinnen*" means: "To win" however unlike "*siegen*" it most often means that you have some gain. It does not neccessarily mean that you win the first prize.

Example:

> Every participant in the sports event is a **winner**, not only the **winner** of the event. He wins new friends, fitness and experience.

In this case the first "winner" might be translated as "*Gewinner*", the second one as "*Sieger*".

However especially children use the word "*Gewinner*" as synonym for the word "*Sieger*"...

> Überwinder

"*Überwinden*" means "to overcome". In the past tense this word means that someone had to face serious problems (a desease, financial problems ...) in the past but he or she could manage that.

If someone suffered from cancer in the past and is healthy now you often say: "*Er hat den Krebs überwunden.*" (He has won the fight against the cancer.)

The word *Überwinder* is used very rarely - so rarely that I don't have an example of a sentence that doesn't sound weird. The word means that the person has managed such a kind of problems.

> Besieger

Although I would understand this word I never heared it before. Are you sure anyone uses it?

> Erster

This simply means "the first".

Especially on sports and games where you could create some kind of rank (first position, second position ...) the winner can be called "*Erster*". Young children often do so.

> Bezwinger

"*Bezwingen*" means to fight against something or someone and to win.

One example is mountain climbing:

When the climber is climing the mountain you say that he is "fighting against the mountain". When he managed to climb the mountain you say: "*Er hat den Berg bezwungen.*" (He has fought against the mountain and won.)

The word is used in other contexts, too.

So a "*Bezwinger*" is someone who has "*bezwungen*" something or someone.

Comment: The origin of "Bezwinger" might  be: "someone who overcame a Zwinger (part of medieval fortification)"!?

Comment: Haven't heard "Besieger" either. If somebody used this word, I would understand it to mean somebody who won against somebody in a war or sports event with the emphasis that the opponent got defeated. There is the word "Besiegter" (with "t") which is somebody who got defeated.

Comment: @user1583209, both words "Bezwingen" and "Zwinger" have same origins, e.g. middle old German "twingen" https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zwinger